# How to make side-by-side blocks fill the rest of the container when one is fixed size?

Tags: css

I have two blocks that are side-by-side. One size is fixed, `90px` and other one is not, I want the other one to extend itself to the rest of the container since container size is will be changing.

Here is fiddle with commends displaying the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.left, .right {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.left {
    background: green;
    width: 90px;
}

.right {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%; // How can I make it fit the rest of the container?
}

.container {
    width: 400px; // This value is NOT STATIC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by pure CSS, here is working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/UYYan/)

1. Make sure filler `element` is last in DOM tree
2. Make sure rest of the elements have `position: relative` specified and width+height

This is nice trick I learned:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="rest"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#container {
    width:50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    min-width: auto;
}
.left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.rest {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

Make the width of `.right` `width: calc(100% - 90px);`

Solution 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/4/ In case of this solution you should probably use divs instead of span since I changed your spans to block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<span class="left"></span>
<span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left, .right {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.left {
    background: green;
    width: 90px;
    float: left
}

.right {
    background: blue;
    width: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 400px; 
}
```

Comment: It can be `400px` it can be `200px`. No, I want them to be side-by-side. Green one to be excatly `90px` and blue one to be the rest of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `float: left` only for the left one

see result: 
http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/2/

also you need `display: block` and `width: auto` for the right one

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is needed to calculate the extra space that can be filled, as the container is not a fixed width.

```
var con = document.querySelector(".container");
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var right = document.querySelector(".right");

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
   calcSize(); 
});

function calcSize() {
    var diff = con.offsetWidth - left.offsetWidth;
    right.style.width = diff + "px";
}

calcSize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/7/

Comment: Well obviously it's not NEEDED but yes this is another solution.

Comment: Yeah is not needed but this is how I would do it. I don't use floats in my layouts if I can help it.

Comment: Can I hear the reason? performance wise and download volume wise this is worse.

Comment: Because with floats you start to lose control of where elements are positioned on a page when you add other content. Mine: http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/8/, yours: http://jsfiddle.net/L6CSG/9/

Comment: Well I shall take floats more seriously then.